# Laravel subquery on custom manyToMany relationship count

Tags: laravel

Let's say in a Post model I have

```php
public function followers()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'post_followers', 'post_id', 'user_id')
    ->as('follower')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

And I now like to do a count where I apply a subquery on that relationship:

```php
$post = Post::with('followers')
  ->withCount([
    'followers as followers_count_total',
    'followers as followers_count_this_month' => function ($q) {
      $q->where('follower.created_at', '>', now()->addDays(30)); // This doesn't work
    },
  ])
  ->firstOrFail();
```

I think that `$q->wherePivot('created_at', '>', now()->addDays(30));` doesn't work because the relationship has a custom name?

Comment: That `wherePivot` clause isn't actually in your code, but the `where()` clause you have has a typo: `'follower.created_at'` would be `'followers.created_at'` (table name is `followers`)

Comment: If I do that I get `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'followers.created_at' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Oh sorry, `followers` is the relationship name; would be `'post_followers.created_at'` if you wanted to target the `pivot` table (does the `pivot` table _have_ a `created_at` timestamp?)

Comment: Ha! OK so I actually had that initially and thought it was not working. Turns out, I have to use `subDays` vs `addDays` in that example. Facepalm...

Comment: Oh yup; that would do it! Unless your records are time travelling, there likely won't be any created 30 days from now  (sidenote, I voted to close as a typo, which has no negative impact or anything, just for housekeeping)